# "Indirect modification of overloaded element of SplFixedArray has no effect"

Tags: php, arrays, spl

Why the following

```
$a = new SplFixedArray(5);
$a[0] = array(1, 2, 3);
$a[0][0] = 12345; // here
var_dump($a);
```

produces

```
Notice: Indirect modification of overloaded element of SplFixedArray has no effect in <file> on line <indicated>
```

Is it a bug? How do you deal with multidimensional SplFixedArrays then? Any workarounds?

Comment: This may help http://hakre.wordpress.com/2010/09/13/indirect-modification-of-overloaded-element-of-has-no-effect/

Comment: @hek2mgl can you think of any workaround?

Comment: I'm still at work. Thinking that it will take some time to find a workaround. Will have a look here later (~1hour)

Comment: @NabinKunwar PHP is 5.5

Answer (score 49, accepted):

First, the problem is related to all classes which implement `ArrayAccess` it is not a special problem of `SplFixedArray` only.

---

When you accessing elements from `SplFixedArray` using the `[]` operator it behaves not exactly like an array. Internally it's `offsetGet()` method is called, and will return in your case an array - **but not a reference** to that array. This means all modifications you make on `$a[0]` will get lost unless you save it back:

Workaround:

```
$a = new SplFixedArray(5);
$a[0] = array(1, 2, 3); 
// get element
$element = $a[0];
// modify it
$element[0] = 12345;
// store the element again
$a[0] = $element;

var_dump($a);
```

Here is an [example using a scalar](http://3v4l.org/qT43k) which fails too - just to show you that it is not related to array elements only.

Comment: Bitteschön :)  Another thinkable workaround might be to sub class `SplFixedArray` and override `offsetGet()` in a way that it returns references for arrays or scalars. But this might lead to side effects which aren't desired.. (because a real array won't return references)

Answer (score 10):

This is actually fixable if you slap a `&` in front of `offsetGet` (assuming you have access to the internals of your `ArrayAccess` implementation):

```
class Dict implements IDict {
    private $_data = [];

    /**
     * @param mixed $offset
     * @return bool
     */
    public function offsetExists($offset) {
        return array_key_exists(self::hash($offset), $this->_data);
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $offset
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function &offsetGet($offset) {
        return $this->_data[self::hash($offset)];
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $var
     * @return string
     */
    private static function hash($var) {
        return is_object($var) ? spl_object_hash($var) : json_encode($var,JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $offset
     * @param mixed $value
     */
    public function offsetSet($offset, $value) {
        $this->_data[self::hash($offset)] = $value;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $offset
     */
    public function offsetUnset($offset) {
        unset($this->_data[self::hash($offset)]);
    }
}
```

Comment: What does adding the `&` do exactly?

Comment: @Yani It allows you to mutate the returned value (as opposed to making a copy of it). i.e., `$dict[$obj] = 5;` will do what you expect (update the dict) instead of doing nothing at all.

Answer (score 0):

Adding my experience with the same error, in case it helps anyone:

I recently imported my code into a framework with a low error-tolerance (Laravel). As a result, my code now throws an exception when I try to retrieve a value from an associative array using a non-existent key. In order to deal with this I tried to implement my own dictionary using the ArrayAccess interface. This works fine, but the following syntax fails:

```
$myDict = new Dictionary();
$myDict[] = 123;
$myDict[] = 456;
```

And in the case of a multimap:

```
$properties = new Dictionary();
$properties['colours'] = new Dictionary();
$properties['colours'][] = 'red';
$properties['colours'][] = 'blue';
```

I managed to fix the problem with the following implementation:

```
<?php

use ArrayAccess;

/**
 * Class Dictionary
 *
 * DOES NOT THROW EXCEPTIONS, RETURNS NULL IF KEY IS EMPTY
 *
 * @package fnxProdCrawler
 */
class Dictionary implements ArrayAccess
{
    // FOR MORE INFO SEE: http://alanstorm.com/php_array_access

    protected $dict;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->dict = [];
    }

    // INTERFACE IMPLEMENTATION - ArrayAccess
    public function offsetExists($key)
    {
        return array_key_exists($key, $this->dict);
    }
    public function offsetGet($key)
    {
        if ($this->offsetExists($key))
            return $this->dict[$key];
        else
            return null;
    }
    public function offsetSet($key, $value)
    {
        // NOTE: THIS IS THE FIX FOR THE ISSUE "Indirect modification of overloaded element of SplFixedArray has no effect"
        // NOTE: WHEN APPENDING AN ARRAY (E.G. myArr[] = 5) THE KEY IS NULL, SO WE TEST FOR THIS CONDITION BELOW, AND VOILA

        if (is_null($key))
        {
            $this->dict[] = $value;
        }
        else
        {
            $this->dict[$key] = $value;
        }
    }
    public function offsetUnset($key)
    {
        unset($this->dict[$key]);
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I did a workaround to this problem extending `SplFixedArray` and overriding `offsetGet()` to return a reference*
But as this [hek2mgl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20053269/indirect-modification-of-overloaded-element-of-splfixedarray-has-no-effect#answer-20053303) mentioned, it could lead to side effects.

I shared the code to do it, because I couldn't find it in other place. Note is not serious implementation, because I'm not even checking the offset exists (I will be glad if someone propose enhancements), but it works:

```
class mySplFixedArray extends SplFixedArray{
        public function &offsetGet($offset) {
            return $this->array[$offset];
        }       
    }
```

I was changing native PHP hash like arrays for these less memory consuming fixed length arrays, and some of the other things I have to change too (either as a consequence of the lazy extending of the class SplFixedArray, or just for not using native arrays) were:

- Creating a manual method for copying my class objects property by property. `clone` didn't worked anymore.
- Use `a[i]!==NULL` to check if the element exists, because `isset()` didn't worked anymore.
- Add an `offsetSet()` method to the extended class too:
  `public function offsetSet($offset,$value) { $this->array[$offset]=$value; }`

(*) I think this overriding is only possible after some PHP version between 5.2.6 and 5.3.4. I couldn't find too much info or code about this problem, but I want to share the solution for other people anyway.

Answer (score -3):

I guess SplFixedArray is incomplete/buggy.

If i wrote an own class and it works like a charm:

```
$a = new \myArrayClass();
$a[0] = array(1, 2, 3);
$a[0][0] = 12345;
var_dump($a->toArray());
```

Output (no notices/warnings here, in strict mode too):

```
array (size=1)
    0 => 
        array (size=3)
            0 => int 12345
            1 => int 2
            2 => int 3
```

Using the [] operator is not a problem (for assoc/mixed arrays too). A right implementation of offsetSet should do the job:

```
public function offsetSet($offset, $value) {
    if ($offset === null) {
        $offset = 0;
        if (\count($this->array)) {
            $keys = \preg_grep( '#^(0|([1-9][0-9]*))$#', \array_keys($this->array));
            if (\count($keys)) {
                $offset = \max($keys) + 1;
           }
        }
    }
    ...
```

But there is only one exception. Its not possible to use the [] operator for offset which does not exist. In our example:

```
$a[1][] ='value'; // Notice: Indirect modification of overloaded...
```

It would throw the warning above because ArrayAccess calls offsetGet and not offsetSet for [1] and the later [] fails. Maybe there is a solution out there, but i did not find it yet. But the following is working without probs:

```
$a[] ='value';
$a[0][] ='value';
```

I would write an own implementation instead of using SplFixedArray. Maybe its possible to overload some methods in SplFixedArray to fix it, but i am not sure because i never used and checked SplFixedArray.

Comment: This is Stackoverflow, not a guessing game!