# Indirect modification of overloaded element of User has no effect

Tags: php, arrays, json, mongodb, laravel

I've already looked at the following, but haven't been able to solve my problem:
 - ["Indirect modification of overloaded element of SplFixedArray has no effect"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20053269/indirect-modification-of-overloaded-element-of-splfixedarray-has-no-effect)

I'm using Laravel 4 with Eloquent. To access a user in the database, I create the following query.

```
$user = User::find(Auth::id())->first();
```

The $user object is represented as the following.

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$id": "56b50fe08525cd0d3e9d8dc4"
  },
  ...
  "splits": {
    "owned": [],
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

I'm currently trying to append a string to the splits->owned array, but I'm having the error "Indirect modification of overloaded property User::$splits has no effect". The error is raised on the third line below.

```
private function generateUserSplits($split) {
    $user = User::find(Auth::id());
    array_push($user->$splits->$owned, $split->id);
    $user->save();
}
```

$split->id contains a string of characters similar to "56b50fe08525cd0d3e9d8dc4".
I've already had a browse around stack overflow for similar answers, and as of yet have had no success.

If anyone could provide some help, it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Are u sure $split array is defined in your User Model??

Comment: $split here is the argument to the function.
$splits is in the json representation of the model above.
In my UserController, this code is executed when a User is created

`        $splits = array(
            "owned" => array(),
            "contributed" => array(),
            "favourites" => array()
        );
        $user->splits = $splits;
`