# Inserting Json in Json in PHP Foreach

Tags: php, json, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to insert json into an existing json object returned by eloquent in Laravel.

```
$fixtures = Fixture::where('week', $week)->get();
foreach($fixtures as $key => $fixture){
        $fixtureinfos = FixtureInfo::where('fixture_id', $fixture[$key]['id'])->get();
        $fixture[$key]['fixtureinfos'] = $fixtureinfos;
 }
```

I am getting the error "Indirect modification of overloaded element of App\Fixture has no effect"

How should I be inserting '$fixtureinfos' into the existing '$fixture'?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This may be related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20053269/indirect-modification-of-overloaded-element-of-splfixedarray-has-no-effect. Even if it's not the same class, the workaround may help.

Comment: Terminus, you are right. It is related. I'll post the solution. Thanks for your help

Comment: I cannot see any [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) in your question.

Comment: It's what Eloquent returns into $fixtures and $fixtureinfos

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Terminus, this is related to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20053269/indirect-modification-of-overloaded-element-of-splfixedarray-has-no-effect).

Here is the solution to the case in this post.

```
$fixtures = Fixture::where('week', $week)->get();
foreach($fixtures as $key => $fixture){
    $fixtureinfos = FixtureInfo::where('fixture_id', $fixture[$key]['id'])->get();
    $arraytemp = $fixtures[$key];
    $arraytemp['fixtureinfos'] = $fixtureinfos;
    $fixtures[$key] = $arraytemp;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should apply relation between those tables

**In Fixture model**

```
function fixtureinfo(){
    return $this->belongsTo(FixtrureInfo::class);
}
```

**In FixtureInfo model**

```
function fixture(){
    return $this->hasOne(Fixtrure::class);
}
```

**Then in controller. You easily to use Eager Loading**

```
$fixtures = Fixture::where('week', $week)->with('fixtureinfo')->get();
```

**Then you can easily to access fixtureinfo like this**

```
$fixtures[0]->fixtureinfo
```

Use a loop if you want