# PHP array element always returns false

Tags: php, arrays, boolean

I'm trying to populate a set of checkboxes based on stored form data. Unfortunately, the isSelected element only seems to return false. Here's the code:

```
if($field['type'] == 'checkbox'){
    $inputs = $field['inputs'];
    $count = '0';
    foreach($inputs as $input){
        if(($user_meta[$input['id']] !== '') && (isset($user_meta[$input['id']]))){
           $select = true;
        }
        else{
            $select = false;
        }
        $field['choices'][$count] = array( 
            'text' => $field['choices'][$count]['text'], 
            'value' => $field['choices'][$count]['value'] , 
            'isSelected' => $select );
        var_dump($select);
        var_dump($field['isSelected']);
        $count = $count + '1';
    }
}
```

The `var_dump` of `$select` correctly returns boolean `true` and `false` values where it should. But the `isSelected` element always returns an empty string. This is true even when I replace the `$select` variable with a hardcoded true value, or use 1 and 0 instead of true and false.

I'm sure I'm missing something very basic, but I've had no luck finding a solution so far. I'd be grateful for any help!

**Edit**

Thanks to @Barmar I have a little more information on the problem. It's failing when I try to assign a value to $field['choices'][$count]['isSelected']. The log shows "PHP Notice: Indirect modification of overloaded element of GF_Field_Checkbox has no effect". Unfortunately, I can't see why that would be a problem here, as from what I can tell that error normally comes from using __get/set methods which I'm not actually making use of in this case. I also tried solutions suggested in ["Indirect modification of overloaded element of SplFixedArray has no effect"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20053269/indirect-modification-of-overloaded-element-of-splfixedarray-has-no-effect) to no avail. Is there some kind of setting or configuration that might be preventing this assignment?

Comment: It should be `var_dump($field['choices'][$count]['isSelected'])`.

Comment: Thanks. That does at least return a boolean value, which makes more sense to me. Still, it doesn't match the value of $select and always returns false.

Comment: Why are you reassigning the element with an array containing the same fields? If you just want to add `isSelected`, just do `$field['choices'][$count]['isSelected'] = $selected;`

Comment: BTW, you should switch the order of the tests here: `if(($user_meta[$input['id']] !== '') && (isset($user_meta[$input['id']]))){` You should test if the variable isset **before** testing if its value is equal to something.

Comment: I can't think of any reason why that would happen in the code you've posted. There must be some difference.

Comment: Turn on `error_reporting(E_ALL)`, make sure you're accessing valid indexes.

Comment: Hey, thanks. I still don't have a solution, but turning on error reporting revealed this error: "PHP Notice: Indirect modification of overloaded element of GF_Field_Checkbox has no effect". Some digging suggests this happens when you try to change the assignment of an element in an array you accessed via the _get method. And that is how I got this array. I'll poke around that rabbit hole and hopefully root out some gremlins there.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I spotted the error. As a note, you don't need to have the $count variable in the array creation since you are going from 0++. Also the count can be shorthanded to $count++;

It looks like this is incorrect `var_dump($field['isSelected']);` and you meant `var_dump($field['choices'][$count]['isSelected']);`

```
$field['choices'][] = array( 
        'text' => $field['choices'][$count]['text'], 
        'value' => $field['choices'][$count]['value'] , 
        'isSelected' => $select );
var_dump($select);
var_dump($field['choices'][$count]['isSelected']);
$count++;
```

Comment: That's the same thing I said in a comment. This trivial error isn't worth writing a real answer for.

Comment: But he also said in a comment that fixing this still doesn't work.

Comment: `$field['choices'][]` is wrong. He's not adding to a new array, he's replacing the element in the same array.

Comment: Good catch on $field['choices'][]; Then there's no need to reassign the values and just update isSelected directly.